# Applying two consecutive transformations on a UIView

Tags: swift, transform

How can I apply a scale and rotation transformation to a view? When I use the code below, only the last transformation is applied.

```
testV.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, keepRotation)
testV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, keepScale, keepScale)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work like this:

```
var transformation1 = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, keepRotation)
var transformation2 = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, keepScale, keepScale)

testV.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformation1, transformation2)
```

Comment: Why you are asking and replying your own questions in just small time?

Comment: If you have answers in just 3 minutes then try to resolve first.